# maven, multimodule project, properties inheritance

Tags: maven, inheritance, properties

For example, I have 3 ejb modules. Name it #1 #2 #3

Also I have 2 ear modules. Name it #4 #5

Module #4 - depends on #1 #2

Module #5 - depends on #2 #3

I need to provide different settings to #2 for different ear builds.

---

It seems that I can't just specify parent projects for #2 - module can have only one parent

Any ideas how to solve this task?

Comment: What kind of 'different settings' are you specifically talking about?

Comment: For example I need to specify DB user/password in persistence.xml Also it may be path to folders for log files in logback.xml  These files must be changed during build cycle

Comment: huh, it is so easy. I make one parent module and some profiles with properties - one profile for each ear. Sorry, I will not post questions at night any more ))